# How to add a layer style effect especially on a highlighted text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, stroke, photoshop-scripting

How can I add an effect on a highlighted text, such as border and other stuff that can be found in Layer styles > Blending options?

Example:

I have this text right here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJgTM.png and I want to give the text below a white stroke around the word "SAMPLE", which currently I worked around by putting a layer mask on it, but when I want to modify the text, it can become hard and you have to readjust it.

But let's say it has like shine options around, and we don't want to overlap things that should not be overlapped.

[image]
For example, in this picture I highlighted the word "SAMPLE" because I only this part in the text should get a stroke effect around it.

Basically like this:

[image]
Here I also put a satin effect from layer styles.

But it wasn't that simple to make.
[image]

I had to do it with mask and if I should ever modify the text I have to redo the mask.

My question is, is there an easier way?

Comment: `Is there an easier way` -- Not really if you want live, editable type, which is expected to change, but also the ability to target some styles specifically on one word.

Comment: The real trick is to not use Photoshop for type.

Answer (score 0):

One trick ...... But let me explain with example:

1, example set up like this:
[image]

2, convert lower line text layer into smart object, then ctrl+J to make a copy layer, this is the trick, these 2 layers link to the same smart object, if you change spelling in that smart object, the 2 layers will change text at the same time. 
[image]

3, add effect to the top layer,
[image]

4, use rectangular markee tool (as large as possible, you may want to add some letters without having to change mask) then make a mask,
[image]

5, now, double click layer thumbnail of any of the top 2 layers, change spelling as you wish, ctrl+S to save changes, you'll get what you want......change mask if needed.
[image]

PS: I don't fully understand your question.... if you want the upper line changes spelling corresondingly, you could also achieve it with smart object - this time there'll be no upper line layer at the beginning, you'll have to make a smart object lower line text layer and copy twice, in one of those two you can move text up making it upper line..... Don't know if you need that.